# How to get the full URL with the current path in Capybara

Tags: ruby, rspec, capybara

I'm new to writing tests in capybara and I'm having trouble getting the current URL of a page. I wrote it like this:

```
url = page.current_url + page.current_path
```

Somehow its just returning the base URL. Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Try this:

```
url = URI.parse(current_url)
```

Comment: `url = URI.parse(current_url).to_s`

Comment: `current_url` gives the exact same response as the line above ^^

Answer (score 17):

from [capybara session doc](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Session#current_url-instance_method): 

Fully qualified URL of the current page

```
def current_url
  driver.current_url
end
```

Path of the current page, without any domain information

```
def current_path
  URI.parse(current_url).path
end
```

I think that what you are doing is not right

Comment: Yeah, I was doing it all wrong. But I will use what you provided in my future work. Thanks.

Comment: @Philidor , am new to RSpec. where we need to define this function? in normal code file or spec file which we create in the spec folder?

Answer (score 7):

you could use `have_current_path`:

```
expect(page).to have_current_path(new_user_path)
```

before seeing that I was doing something like:

```
  def current_path
    current_uri = URI.parse(page.current_url)
    current_path = current_uri.path
    current_path += "?#{current_uri.query}" if current_uri.query.present?
    current_path
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `has_current_path` matcher and match for full URLs.

```rb
expect(page).to have_current_path('https://example.com', url: true)
```

Have a look at the Capybara test suite for more examples:
[`has_current_path_spec.rb#L54`](https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara/blob/c0cbf4024c1abd48b0c22c2930e7b05af58ab284/lib/capybara/spec/session/has_current_path_spec.rb#L54).